# C# Query when any of the condition is not null

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I want to find the data in database when any one of the conditions meet.

Pasted my code so that it will be more clear

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(string FirstName = null, string LastName = null, int Year = 0, int Month = 0)
    {

        var users = _context.Users.AsQueryable();
        if (FirstName != null || LastName != null || Year != 0 || Month != 0)
        {
            users = _context.Users.Where(u => (u.CreatedAt.Year == Year) && (u.CreatedAt.Month == Month));
        }
        else
        {
            users = _context.Users;
        }

        return users.ToList();

    }
```

This code is doing a simple search in database

```
where year == createdAt.year &&
              month == createdAt.month && 
              LastName == abc && 
              FirstName == abc
```

However, if one of the condition is 0/null, then the database will return nothing since there is no month/year == 0 or firstname/lastname == null; What I want is, if year/month/lastname/firstname is 0/null, then just ignore it and check other condition.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// first style
users = _context.Users.Where(u => 
    (Year != 0 ? u.CreatedAt.Year == Year : true) &&
    (Month != 0 ? u.CreatedAt.Month == Month : true) &&
    (FirstName != null ? u.FirstName == FirstName : true) &&
    (LastName != null ? u.LastName == LastName : true));
// second style
users = _context.Users.Where(u => 
    (Year == 0 || u.CreatedAt.Year == Year) &&
    (Month == 0 || u.CreatedAt.Month == Month) &&
    (FirstName == null || u.FirstName == FirstName) &&
    (LastName == null || u.LastName == LastName));
```

I think you should check each condition separately like this.
For example when Year != 0 and every other para is not set, your original code will return nothing.

Comment: The second style is the correct answer. The first one will give some warning about simplifying the ternary expression. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add your logic to the LINQ query to check conditions.

```
users = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id !=0 
                               && x.FirstName != null 
                               && x.FirstName != null 
                               && x.Year != 0 
                               && x.Month != 0)
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: This will search all the data that is not null right? I want to make it search the database with the parameters I given. I have added the whole method above in order to better understanding.

Comment: So this code is doing a simple search in database where year == createdAt.year && month == createdAt.month. However, if one of the condition is 0, then the database will return nothing since there is no month/year == 0; What I want is, if year/month is 0, then just ignore it and check other condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `users = _context.Users.Where(x => 
                               && (x.FirstName != null || x.FirstName == FirstName) 
                               && (x.Year == 0 || x.Year == Year) 
                               && (x.Month == 0 || x.Month == Month)
                              .ToList();`

Comment: This is a really good hint, thanks. However, it need some modification in order to make it works. In stead of x.Year!=0, we should check Month == 0 || x.Month == Month, so that whenever the month is 0, it will be true and not check the second one, right?

Comment: Yep, I had the same situation 2 weeks ago doing a filter. Tell us if it works :D

Comment: I tried, in your solution, you checked (x.year/month/firstname != null/0), but you didnt check the parameter year/month/firstname == 0/null, then year/month/firstname can still be 0 and be passed in. Then it still doesnt work. ivooQ's answer works. See his second style.